# How do I create an Atom representation with Restlet?

Tags: java, rss, restlet, rome, atom-feed

I want to create atom xml representations for my REST resources using Restlet.

Should I (can I?) use ROME or just use the Atom extension for Restlet?

What's the best way to go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is usually what suits your needs best :)

If you want to be up and running fast, you may prefer to use a helper library. Here I would also suggest to take a look at [Apache Abdera](http://abdera.apache.org/).

The part that may be of concern with helper libraries is usually the number of external dependencies. If this is a deal breaker for you, then you may want to consider to write the code yourself.

Comment: I ended up going with the Restlet Atom classes, one less library to deal with. Now that I've played with that a bit I might try out Abdera and Rome just to compare.

Answer (score 0):

Creating atom xml isn't that difficult, I did it without helper libraries.
You can look at the source code [here](http://kenai.com/projects/jecars/sources/jecars-repository/show).